# how to get WebRequest.OnBeforeRequestDetailsType in manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How do we get access to `headerDetails` in manifest V3?
Docs are vague, and google search did not give any fruitful results.

I am looking to access all urls with a particular string, and get that data and show it in popup.

this is my current implementation v2, but `WebRequest` has been deprecated in V3

```
function processRequests(details: WebRequest.OnBeforeRequestDetailsType): void {
    if (!details.requestBody?.raw) {
        return
    }

    const decoder = new TextDecoder()
    const requestBody = decoder.decode(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)

    const waMessages = getMessages(requestBody)
}

function getMessages(requestBody: string): HttpRequestMessages {
    const messages = requestBody.split('\n').filter((_, index) => index > 2)
    return messages.reduce<HttpRequestMessages>((acc, message) => {
        if (message) {
            const { meta, payload } = getEnvelop(message)
            const [timestamp,,schemaName,,,id] = meta.split(',')
            if (schemaName === '') {
                const isoDatetime = (new Date(parseInt(timestamp, 10))).toISOString()
                acc[id] = {
                    isoDatetime,
                    message: JSON.parse(payload),
                }
            }
        }
        return acc
    }, { })
}
```

Comment: 1) WebRequest is not deprecated. Only its blocking mode is. Nothing's changed otherwise. 2) WebRequest.OnBeforeRequestDetailsType is not an official type. Try switching to the official [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) package - note that it uses different spelling of these types.

Comment: @wOxxOm its not supported anymore, the new way is `declarativeNetRequest`. also with event pages we can no use it.  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/#:~:text=Are%20you%20currently%20using%20the%20blocking%20version%20of%20chrome.webRequest%3F

Comment: and do you mean use `chrome-types` instead of `@types/chrome` ? as currently  am using `"@types/chrome": "0.0.193",`

Comment: WebRequest **is** definitely supported. Only its **blocking** mode isn't, as explicitly stated in your link. Use the link for the chrome-types package I gave in my comment.